# css - Transparent scrollbar while image in background of body

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, background-image

I have this problem: I have an image and rgba in background of body, and want to make my scrollbar's background transparent. For some reason it doesn't want to be transparent and in stead it's white. I don't know what's wrong:(
HTML:

```
<body>
<p><!--- TEXT ---></p>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body
    {
      background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.5), rgba(255,255,255,0.5)), url("http://picalls.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Amazing-night-sky.jpg") center top no-repeat fixed;
    }

::-webkit-scrollbar
    {
      background: transparent;
      width: 10px;
    }
```

Jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/bc9Lc5rj/

Comment: I would recommend you to use a scrollbar javascript to colorize/skin your scrollbar. The problem with CSS3 is that this isn't supported for old browsers now. So it often happens that what's looking good for modern browsers screws up on the most old ones. Especially if the CSS3 tag is relative new.

Comment: @Sascha Oh you're so wrong, something that can be done with css is much better then using javascript :) User can not disable styles loading..

Comment: @Adéla: But it isn't cross-browser-compatible then.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example found [here](https://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/), it should be possible:

```css
html {
  overflow: auto;
}
body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #FF0000;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar,
::-webkit-scrollbar-track,
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  background: transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at pharetra massa, vel molestie lectus. Vivamus vehicula tempor arcu ac fringilla. Mauris varius vel nibh quis vehicula. Duis scelerisque suscipit feugiat. Cras ornare dolor nibh, vel suscipit
    eros volutpat eget. Phasellus id nisl mi. Donec laoreet ipsum ac tortor dapibus lobortis. Morbi dictum, arcu egestas dictum porta, eros ex rutrum ex, a rhoncus dui sapien vel orci. Morbi id ornare justo. Proin a blandit tortor. Praesent et ultricies
    diam, et lacinia odio. Morbi metus risus, auctor sit amet semper vel, interdum ut elit. Donec consequat interdum purus. Donec iaculis pellentesque lorem vitae malesuada. Aliquam sed ullamcorper elit. In mattis neque eu leo ullamcorper sodales. Class
    aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse id urna nec orci rhoncus cursus. Pellentesque pulvinar orci eget metus aliquam, vel rutrum erat maximus. Nullam pharetra mi dui, sed ullamcorper orci
    tristique vel. Curabitur ut eleifend orci. Pellentesque nec ipsum ut ipsum cursus consectetur. Nunc eu mattis ante, ac scelerisque lacus. Sed in venenatis mauris. Integer sodales libero et ante pellentesque lacinia. Duis iaculis feugiat nunc, in malesuada
    turpis faucibus vel. Cras congue ornare nulla non tincidunt. Donec sed commodo felis. Proin dignissim blandit tellus, id sagittis turpis fermentum quis. Integer lacus quam, finibus nec posuere et, sagittis eget purus. Sed et dolor venenatis, pulvinar
    ante sed, suscipit magna. Morbi nec auctor magna, id elementum ipsum. Morbi quis ligula libero. Suspendisse in mi eget enim finibus blandit. Praesent lobortis massa nec est tristique pharetra. Praesent pellentesque, metus non congue varius, diam enim
    gravida nisi, ut ultrices eros nulla et nisi. Maecenas molestie sit amet ex sit amet feugiat. Maecenas sodales augue eget est scelerisque, id tincidunt velit rhoncus. Quisque ut fermentum risus, eget posuere nulla. Morbi accumsan orci quis pretium
    dictum. Fusce ornare lectus dui, et laoreet nulla mattis posuere. Aliquam maximus gravida finibus. Duis posuere metus eros, ultrices euismod odio posuere sed. Quisque tempus tortor nec facilisis facilisis. Sed arcu elit, bibendum vitae tincidunt id,
    auctor quis justo. Nam auctor quam a pretium accumsan. Sed ornare, nisl a posuere lacinia, erat eros pulvinar orci, vitae congue lorem ligula sed justo. Vestibulum pulvinar velit ut molestie tristique. Quisque feugiat purus nisl. Sed pharetra nec
    metus vel sollicitudin. Vestibulum tempor ipsum et mauris interdum, quis imperdiet nisl semper.
  </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally would recommend using a jQuery or javascript plugin for this sort of thing. My reason being... browser support! Why should webkit browsers get all the fun stuff?

I've used this plugin a few times http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com. It works pretty well. There are a ton out there.

All you need to do is install the plugin and initialize it.

```
$('.container').jScrollPane();
```

Hope this helps!